# Ionic 2 module loading issue

Tags: ionic2

I'm new to ionic 2 and still learning a bit and I have a problem.

I have a simple library written in JavaScript; I made a definition file for it in `declrations.d.ts` file in the src/ folder

Inside one of my typescript components I'm writing: `import { myClass } from 'myLibiraryModule'` and the compiler doesn't show any errors. However, when I save the file and the build process starts in ionic I get an error in the console: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "myLibiraryModule"`

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: this error occurs because of wrong path you have given

Comment: on the ionic website it said that external libiraries that i make definition files for shold go in a `declarations.d.ts` file into the src/ folder however it didn't speak about the actual .js file place...i put it ina lib/ folder under www/ folder but i couldn't find any info about that..any thought on how to fix this ?